# What is the connector type of the Sony Dualshock 4 controller's EXT port

Tags: connector, identification

I'm trying to find information on the connector type for the EXT port on Sony's Dualshock 4 controllers.  It's entirely possible that it's some custom thing they threw together, but I'm having difficulty determining even that.

The female receptacle on the controller looks like this:
[image]

A male power-only mate for it looks like this:
[image]

The male connector is 6.5 x 2.0mm with pins at the four corners along the length.  Does anyone have information for this connector?

EDIT:  Some additional information.  It appears to be the same jack that Sony uses for minidisc players.  Most MD service manuals reference it as J301 and offer a part number of 1-793-288-62 for the receptacle, but that doesn't seem to offer up any information either.

Comment: Most likely custom

Comment: @DerStrom8 - yeah, that's what it's looking like more and more.  Just edited the initial question with some additional info, but unfortunately it hasn't helped me any.